# Spring Security OAuth2 integration into an existing username/password workflow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I've only been using Spring for the past two weeks, so bear with me please. I'm making an API, meaning I'm not using Spring for any frontend, if that was the case, this would be pretty straightforward I feel like. I have a functional register/login workflow. Users are saved in MySQL (User entity extending UserDetails and a service extending UserDetailsService - the standard DAO stuff), logging in and persisting the authentication context is handled by the following endpoint

```
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> login(
            @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication
    ) {
        if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new LoginResponse(false, "Already logged in", new UserProfile((User) authentication.getPrincipal())));
        }
        Authentication newAuthentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.login(), loginRequest.password())
        );
        SecurityContext context = securityContextHolderStrategy.createEmptyContext();
        context.setAuthentication(newAuthentication);
        securityContextHolderStrategy.setContext(context);
        securityContextRepository.saveContext(context, request, response);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(
                new LoginResponse(true, "Logged in", new UserProfile((User) newAuthentication.getPrincipal()))
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
        return new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
        );
    }
```

Now I also need to enable 3rd party authentication options. Upon successful authentication, I need to create a new user and store it in a DB alongside their token (in a separate table I suppose, to allow for multiple providers yielding the same User principal?). I'd also like to handle the session myself like I did in the /login endpoint. I've looked at a successHandler but from the source code, it looks like it pretty much just handles the final redirection so that's a no-go. So at the end of the day, regardless of the user's authentication method, I want to end up with a User principal in the security context. It honestly feels like writing up my own OAuth2 authentication would be easier than plugging into the existing infrastructure, but I would really rather be able to plug in and let the framework do what it's good at.

Comment: I would suggest that if you want to learn how a basic login scenario is performed is to implement FormLogin as declared in the spring security documentation, and then step through the code to see how that is implemented. Security is not something you make up as tou go, thats when you end up with insecure logins. Most logins (if not all) are implemented in accordance to a RFC, Basic login is one, Oauth2 is a different one. So if you are serious about building a login from scratch you should follow the rfcs that exist

Comment: Trust me, I really don't want to implement anything from scratch I was just stating that it feels like less trouble than trying to find out how to leverage Spring Security into accomplishing my goal.

Comment: since your goal is not clear from your question its very hard for us to advice you. The code you have posted is sort of what FormLogin already does, so use that. You need to enable 3rd party auth options and im onboard with that. You dont mention any of what type of authentication against which third parties. You then say you must store a user in a DB, alongside a token, what token? Why do you need to store a user? So a lot of the details are very unclear here. We can give you a full solution, i suggest you read the architecture chapter in ths spring security docs if its hard to use

Answer (score 1):

Creating new users, storing user data and authenticating users (doing the real stuff with forms and token issuance), in OAuth2 world, is the responsibility of authorization server.

So you might start by looking how you can integrate an authorization server with your existing user database. There are plenty of offers either "on premise" (like Keycloak), "in the cloud" (Auth0, Okta and Amazon Cognito, are just samples among many offers), or "do it yourself" with `spring-authorization-server` (this probably requires more knowledge of the protocol than you have). All the ones I listed have some user federation features ("login with ...").

Once this is done, you'll have to turn your application(s) into an OAuth2 client (or into a set of OAuth2 clients and OAuth2 resource servers).